# RegEx to remove /** */ and // ** **// php comments

Tags: php, regex, comments

***ReGex newbie here.***

I need to remove two different style comments from PHP files using RegEx.

I've found this expression to run in the BBEdit text editor:

`\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/`

and it removes comments in the first style, like below:

`/** This comment gets removed with my regex */`

But it doesn't remove these style comments:

`// ** This comment has the double leadng-trailng slashes ** //`

I don't know why there is a mix of the two different types of comments, and there are only a few of the `//` comments, but I need to delete them all.

Adding another slash to the search, i.e.

`\/\\*[\s\S]*?\*\/`

makes the expression greedy and it removes single slashes in non-commented code. A working expression will require obviously more complexity than that :)

Comment: I think the second is not a mix of 2 types, it's just the single-line  comment style using `//`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
~//?\s*\*[\s\S]*?\*\s*//?~
```

This works.Just added another \ and space eaters to your answer.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lK9zP6/6

Comment: This works great. And regex101 is a great site to play around with regex; I didn't know about it before. Thanks.

Comment: @songdogtech yes it is.Youare welcome.There's one https://www.debuggex.com/ as well.To visualise .

Answer (score 5):

PHP has got a built-in function for that:

```
php_strip_whitespace($filename);
```

Comment: This is excellent, I provided an answer based on regex but +1 because you used a built-in function.

Comment: A php function solution is good to know and I may use it in the future; but I need to run the regex in BBedit to clean a file that is being opened and edited. And, strip_whitespace removes all whitespace and compacts the code too much for clean editing.

Comment: @FedericoPiazza since you love this answer, why not write a php script:

<?php 
 $file = $_GET["file_name"];
 $new_content = php_strip_whitespace(file_get_contents($file));
 file_put_contents($file, $new_content);
?>

and call it like this: http://localhost/stripwhite.php?file=myfile.php

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
\/\*.*?\*\/|\/\/.*?\n
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/qH6nQ2/4)**

[image]

As **[Hwnd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2206004/hwnd)** pointed in this answer, if you change the delimiter to `~` you can use the cleaned regex:

```
/\*.*?\*/|//.*?\n
```

Comment: Thanks, these work, but @vks beat you to a working answer, as your first draft removed all comments and code, too.

Comment: @songdogtech Thanks for the comment. Btw, you are free to choose the best answer for you. Thanks for the +1