# Regex php multiline comment (Meld)

Tags: php, regex, diff, meld

I need to diff two different version of the same app.
The files are signed with a licences and that license has changed.

I don't want that files that contain the license only diff are signed as different.

I use `Meld` as diff software and it allows for regex.

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the License ....
 *
 */
```

There are similar questions but none is working for me:

1. [RegEx to remove /** */ and // ** **// php comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610603/regex-to-remove-and-php-comments)
2. [How can I perform a diff that ignores all comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504059/how-can-i-perform-a-diff-that-ignores-all-comments)

Regex tried:

```
\/\*.*?\*\/|\/\/.*?\n
~//?\s*\*[\s\S]*?\*\s*//?~
```

Actually this one looks to works but I'm not sure it is filtering too much:

```
\*.*
```

**UPDATE:**
This is not possible:
https://mail.gnome.org/archives/meld-list/2011-December/msg00004.html

> While the filter code in Meld
>   will happily accept a regex that covers (and removes) multiple lines,
>   this causes line mismatches between the text the diff sees and the
>   text that we display, so all of the change blocks will be wrong.

Different approach is to remove the lines from the files before process them into meld.

Comment: can you tell the specific pattern you tried?

Comment: Please try some simple regex first to see if it works at all, like `\d+` to match digits.

Comment: I tried it and it works fine ( if for example the license show 2006 on one side and 2009 on the other this is not counted as a diff )

Comment: @rock321987 I am very bad at regex, I keep forgetting them ... 
I have tried the pattern in the mentioned answer without any luck ( I ll add them to the question )

Comment: in meld press "Ctrl+H" and use this regex :- `(?s)/\*(.*?)\*/` or `/\*([\S\s]*?)\*/`

Comment: @rock321987 If I use any of them nothing is matched

Comment: And if you use `/\*[^*]*\*+([^/*][^*]*\*+)*/`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew same no diff

Comment: Ok, I see two asterisks. Try `/\*+[^*]*\*+([^/*][^*]*\*+)*/`. If you copy//paste the pattern from comments make sure it has no garbage chars SO adds inside for better formatting.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew same no diff

Comment: Maybe it's not possible at all. https://mail.gnome.org/archives/meld-list/2011-December/msg00004.html     I played around with meld; it finds multiline comments fine (Ctrl+h), but as soon as you use the regex as text filter in comparison, it won't accept multiline solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
\s*\/\*.*|\s*\*.*
```

Well obviously meld doesn't accept all python regex as a text filter, no multiline nor "|" inside brackets. 
So this solution excludes lines beginning with a star and "/*" with optional spaces. It does not filter out all php comments precisely, but may well work for your files.

Also have a look at that:
https://mail.gnome.org/archives/meld-list/2011-December/msg00004.html

Answer (score 0):

this regex is easier for multiline usage:

```
  .*\/\*[^\/]+\/\s
```

Comment: did you try it with Meld diff program ?